# Как дождаться завершение анимации ? Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

При выключении панели (метод Hide): включить анимацию, дождаться завершения анимации, а только потом выключать объект (методом SetActive(false)).
Event system

Answer (score 0):

Если для переключения состояний вы используете Mecanim, то вы можете использовать [StateMachineBehaivour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html). Такой скрипт навешивается на состояние анимации и в нем можно определить обработку для входа в состояние, выход, изменение инверсной кинематики, на update и пересчет анимации